# ZipFile Entry FulllName Folder Oblique Line sometimes '\' sometimes '/' direction change

Tags: c#

I use a method to get the FullName property in ZipFile

```
public static string GetAllFullName(string zipPath)
{
    string s = "";
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            s += entry.FullName + "\n";
        }
    }
    return s;
}

string s = GetAllFullName(zipPath);
//save the string to SaveFilePath File(such as txt)
File.WriteAllText(SaveFilePath, s, Encoding.Default);
```

then I can see All FullName in a zip.

And In my case, I get a zipfile from others and print the FullName, the result is  (part of all result)

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll
WMS.Silverlight.Languages.dll
zh-Hans\System.Windows.Data.resources.dll
Assets\AppMenu.xml
Assets\Configuration.xml
Assets\Resource.xml
Image\Lock16.png
```

Then I unzip the file in a folder, and choose all files and right click use winrar to zip to .zip again.

And I print that zip file get(part of all result)

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll
WMS.Silverlight.Languages.dll
Assets/
Assets/AppMenu.xml
Assets/Configuration.xml
Assets/Resource.xml
dlls/
dlls/System.Windows.Controls.Extensions.dll
Image/
Image/Lock16.png
Image/Login.png
Image/WMS_Login_bar.png
Image/WMS_Logo_s.png
```

I find the direction of the oblique line change(that line represent folder same as general),

Why the same zipfile by just doing like this can change the direction of the line?

What I'm doing now need to recognize fullname to do something, but if the direction can change like this,

it cause a big problem, because if I add fullname by '/',  maybe other do some zip action and the direction change so what i add will be unrecognizable.

What is the reason to this condition and how to determine when will the direction turn and turn to which direction?

Comment: the path separator is platform dependent. In .NET, use System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar and System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar to see which are valid. Most modern operating system shells will by now accept both, for example when I enter "c:/windows" in my Windows 8.1 explorer, it correctly expands to C:\Windows.